# Compare vectors and add missing elements

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I need a function like this:

```
vector a;matrix A(a.size(),vector(9));

vector b;matrix B(b.size(),vector(9));

....

vector n;matrix N(n.size(),vector(9));

for(all vectors and matrices given){

     if(vector[i] not in other vector){
         put missing element to vector at position i
         put zero vector to B at position i
     }
}
```

I want to give you a case example to make it a bit clearer:

```
a=[name,place]; A=[vector[names],vector[place]]
b=[name,religion]; B=[vector[names], vector[religion]]
c=[place,religion]; C=[vector[place],vector[religion]]
```

The aim is now to end up with `a=b=c=[name,place,religion]` and `A~B~C=[vector[names],vector[place],vector[religion]]`

Where the vectors in the A,B and C are still holding the original data, as well as zero vectors in the case the property was originally not there.

In each vector all the elements are different from each other (so no `vec=[1,1,2]` or similar)

Im sorry about that very abstract description. I hope one gets what I need, otherwise just ask :-)

Thanks already for your help!

Comment: How do you deal with ambiguous cases? Assuming you have `v1=[1 2 2]` and `v2=[1 2 3]` what's your desired output? `[1 2 2 3]` or `[1 2 3]` or `[1 2 3 2]`?

Comment: Fortunately I can be sure that each element in a vector appears only once

Comment: you question is unclear.

Comment: I hope my supplement helps

Answer (score 0):

As for the vectors at least, you could create a `set`, insert all items from all vectors into the set, and then copy from the set into all vectors. Then you should have all data from all vectors without duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I think I've been somehow unclear. The thing is not only to have all elements out of all vectors, but also having zero vectors in the corresponding line of the matrix for each element not present in a vector..